# How to check if my return value is used or was assigned at all to some variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Why do I need this?

For instance I have a method which returns an object (VKRequest) and looks like this:

```
VKRequest *request = [[VKUser currentUser] info];
```

A programmer can then initiate request as follows:

```
[request start];
```

If request should start immediately after method call, programmer should write following code:

```
[VKUser currentUser].startAllRequestsImmediately = YES;
[[VKUser currentUser] info];
```

What I really want is to eliminate startAllRequestsImmediately property from VKUser class and perform requests immediately if returned value isn't used.

Is it possible at all?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you're wanting to do, at least. There is no idea at runtime of "Am I assigned to a variable?" Your two options are to either have a parameter that specifies whether to start the request immediately, or have different methods for "get this thing immediately" and "get this thing after I say `start`".

Answer (score 0):

A method/object should not care about what happens to a return value after it exits. It seems like your wanting to force poor coupling.

Another thought is that this sounds a bit like Apples NSURLConnection. See:

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately
```

Comment: I know about NSURLConnectionDelegate and this method, but it's not what I really want :)